# i want to fetch data from db get by name not by is id by clicking the hyper link

Tags: php, codeigniter, fetch

i am new in code igniter i am trying to fetch the data of all jobs of same location in my view 
i write some code but when i try to get the data its gives me single data i want to fetch all data of same location 
here is my controler

```
public function location($location){
    $data['jobs'] = $this->edituser_model->getBlogBylocation($location); 
    $this->load->view('locwise' , ['data'=>$data]);
}
```

and model is

```
 public function getBlogBylocation($location){
            $this->db->select('*');

        $this->db->like('location', $location);
        $query = $this->db->get('jobs');
       if($query->num_rows() > 0){
        return $query->row();
       }else {
        return false;
       }

    }
```

and my view is

```
<?php foreach ($data as $key => $data): ?> 
                <div class="job-box">
                    <div class="company-logo">

                    </div>




        <div class="row">



            <div class="col-lg-12">
                  <div class="alert alert-success alert-2" role="alert">
                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                           Recently Posted Jobs in <?php echo $data->location?>
                        Citi</div>
        <div class="row">
                <div class="job-box">

                    <div class="description">
                        <div class="float-left">

                                <h5 class="title"><a href="<?php echo site_url('candidate/jobs_detail/' .$data->id);?>"><?php echo $data->job_title?></a></h5>
                            <div class="candidate-listing-footer">



                                <ul>

                                    <li><i class="flaticon-pin">&nbsp;</i><?php echo $data->location?></li>
                                    <li><i class="flaticon-money">&nbsp;</i><?php echo $data->salary?></li>
                                    <li><i class="flaticon-work">&nbsp;</i><?php echo $data->timing?></li>
                                    <!--<li><i class="flaticon-honor">&nbsp;</i><?php echo $jobs->qualification?></li>
                                     <li><i class="flaticon-notepad">&nbsp;</i><?php echo $jobs->experience?></li>-->

                                </ul>&nbsp;

                                <h6>Deadline:<?php echo $data->deadline?></h6>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="div-right">
                            <a href="<?php echo site_url('candidate/edit/' .$data->id);?>" class="apply-button">Apply Now</a>
                            <!--<a href="#"><i class="flaticon-heart favourite"></i></a>-->

                        </div>

                    </div>

                </div>



                       </div>
                       </div><!--end row-->


            </div>

        </div>
         <?php endforeach ?>
    </div>
```

i want to show multi record not single by clicking the hyper link 
Many Thanks in advance 
Junaid Amin

Comment: any one plz help

Comment: Can I see the structure of your database?

Comment: did you tried `->result();` instead of `->row();` in your model ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please update your Controller method, Model method and View as follows:

`Controller::Method`:

```
public function location($location){
    $data['jobs'] = $this->edituser_model->getBlogBylocation($location); 
    $this->load->view('locwise' , $data);
}
```

`Model::Method`:

```
 public function getBlogBylocation($location){
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->like('location', $location);
    $query = $this->db->get('jobs');

    if($query->num_rows() > 0){
        return $query->result();
    } else {
        return false;
    }
 }
```

`View`:

```
<?php foreach ($jobs as $row): ?>

//Your staff goes here (i.e. $row->name_of_properties)

<?php endforeach ?>
```

Comment: @JunaidAmin Sure, try it out. Let me know also if it is not solved.

Comment: To mark an answer as accepted, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.

Answer (score 0):

**pass name instead of id in you a tag and make route for that inside config/routes file**

```
$route['location/(:any)'] = 'controller_name/function_name/$1';
public function location($location){
    $data['jobs'] = $this->edituser_model->getBlogBylocation($location); 
    $this->load->view('locwise' , ['data'=>$data]);
}
```